# Update all values of a column with another column value in the same row except if duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to replace all username column values with the email column values of the same row, like this:

```
UPDATE members_member
SET username = email
```

Unfortunately, the email column contains duplicates while username must be unique. Therefore, I want to skip the duplicate emails from being queried. After the query ran, the username and email value should be the same. How can I achieve this using a mysql query?

***Edit: I know this question is bad, but I can't delete it.***

Comment: have you asked your stakeholders what should happen to duplicate accounts with the same email? how should the multiple accounts be merged into 1?

Comment: `What would the mysql query be like` ... tell us what the final data should be like, and maybe someone can answer.  How to do want to handle the case where an `email` appears more than once?

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  We don't know what to do when the data violates your constraints.

Comment: Are there any NULL values in the username column?

Comment: You have duplicates in your table but you haven't explained how to deal with the duplicates, that is which one should be updated and what should be done with the other one? You also seem to have rows where username is already an email address and other(s) that have the same email address for another username. Maybe you should delete this question while you consider how to handle all types of duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the update to non-duplicated emails:

```
update members_member mm join
       (select mm2.email
        from members_member mm2
        group by mm2.email
        having count(*) = 1
       ) mme
     set mm.username = mm.email;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It still gives the error for duplicate username entries, so it doesn't skip duplicate emails

Comment: @Vincent . . . In that case, you have existing member names that are causing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it all in one query. Sometimes it makes it simpler to do it over a few queries with tmpTables.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpUpdateEmails AS SELECT DISTINCT email, members_member_id FROM members_member;
UPDATE members_member m 
INNER JOIN tmpUpdateEmails e ON m.members_member_id = e.members_member_id
SET m.username = e.email;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpUpdateEmails;
```

Comment: This doens't fix the problem of having duplicate entries for the email column.

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicate entries?